# How to get Application Max Memory Limit in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to get the **Application max allocated memory** detail, for this i have used `DeviceExtendedProperties` like this

```
long maxBytes = (long)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit");
```

but it throws an exception `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.` and the stack trace is

```
at Microsoft.Phone.Info.ExtendedPropertiesHelper.GetValue(String propertyName, GetValueImplDelegate getValueImpl)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue(String propertyName)
```

i can get `long currentBytes =(long)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage");` properly but wont get `ApplicationWorkingSetLimit`.

I go through some blogs and googling for some solution for this i found that DeviceExtendedProperties is **deprecated** and in place of that `DeviceStatus` class is provided.

In `DeviceStatus` there is a property called `ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit` which gives **Application max memory Limit**

but

when using this class application shows error **class not found** for `DeviceStatus` in `Microsoft.Phone.Info` package. i am Using Windows Phone 7.0 SDK.

Is DeviceStatus class present in WP7.0 or not?

Please help me for this problem of getting **ApplicationMaxMemoryLimit** in some other way or am I doing some wrong?

Comment: Why do you need it and why are you still targeting 7.0

Comment: I want this memory Max limit for freeing some memory which i stored in Bitmaps before memory crunch, and for targeting 7.0 because we have some 7.0 targeting devices.

Comment: You shouldn't be targetting 7.0 anymore, all devices have had 7.1 upgrades.

Comment: Please see the following with regard to why you should be targetting 7.1 and not 7.0 : "Paving the way for new features" : http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/04/24/two-marketplace-changes-and-how-they-affect-you.aspx

Comment: Cant i get **Application max allocated memory** using `DeviceExtendedProperties` for WP7.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeviceStatus` is not available in the 7.0 SDK. You have to update your applications to target 7.1 at least - all other builds are deprecated. Remember, that 7.0 applications will no longer be supported in the Windows Phone Marketplace.